# How to be 508 compliant using jQuery UI modal dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, iframe, section508

I'm trying to use the jQuery-UI modal dialog.  However, the html that's created by jQuery includes an iframe that's empty or has no alt tag value.  This get's flagged as a 508 violation.  Has anyone found a way to use the jQuery-UI modal dialog that is 508 compliant?

Comment: Make sure to let the jQuery team know about this, as they claim that UI has a "focus on accessibility."

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "alt" attribute to the jQuery control.  $("elem").attr("alt", "some text").

You can add it to you component definition if the attribute is available for that control.

Does this help?